# Is there a shortcut for the "Home" button in Citrix Virtual Desktop?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, user-interface, virtual-desktop, citrix

Is there a shortcut for the "Home" button in Citrix Virtual Desktop (CDViewer)?
Or is there a way to configure it?

[image]

I am **not** searching for the shortcut to swap between full-screen and window-mode, but for pressing the Home button which returns me from the VDI directly to my host computer.

It's extremely annoying that I have to use the mouse to swap between the computers. To get from my host computer to VDI, I can just use Ctrl+Tab to the Desktop Viewer process, however I have not found any efficient keyboard-based way of getting back.

Comment: did you  find a shortcut ?

Comment: @AdirD No, I didn't :( However I change the project and I do not have to use Citrix anymore :)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd>- then use the Arrowkeys.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot verify your answer since I am now on another project where I do not have to use remote desktop at all, thanks goddess :) and I have no Citrix client at all at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

As [Kai suggested](https://superuser.com/a/1731411/399707), you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd>. I just wanted to add:

- On Lenovo keyboards without a <kbd>Pause</kbd> key, you can use <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> instead
- Instead arrowing down and enter, you can simply press <kbd>H</kbd>